# Iterate through every entry or posts in apache roller weblog

Tags: velocity, blogger, apache-roller, weblog

I am creating a blog using apache roller 5.xx version

I am able to design templates with default macros but I don't know how to write custom programs to it. I am fighting with this pager thing for almost 2 days with no solution now

Can anybody assist me to iterate through the entries obtained in pager using below codes.

```
   #set($pager = $model.getWeblogEntriesPager()) 
   #showWeblogEntriesPager($pager)
```

I want don't want to show entries using #showWeblogEntriesPager($pager) macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at the [internal implementation](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/roller/trunk/app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/velocity/weblog.vm?revision=1614802&view=markup#l174) of #showWeblogEntriesPager and confirm it was not something you could leverage?

Comment: thanks Glen, My bad I was fiddling things weblog.vm without knowing I should be dealing things Entry.vm. Finally my blog is ready :) I would say apache roller is awesome on seeing how easy it is to create a blog

Comment: And thanks for showing the internal implementation, I will check this too. It is really useful